# CouchDB View Sort by Value

Tags: node.js, sorting, couchdb, nano, couchdb-nano

I am looking for a poor perfomance solution to sort my couchdb view by value (because large data). I am using on my NodeJS Application the "nano" package to get the database/view connection.

I created a CouchDB View Map Function configure a key value pair and the Reduce to _count:

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.msg, 1);
}
```

To get my View i am using:

```
alice.view('VIEWNAME', 'INDEXNAME', {'group': true).then((body) => { 
body.rows.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.key + " " + doc.value);
 }
}
```

The View returns for example "Hello" as doc.key and "155" as doc.value. So i have 155 Documents with the Key Hello.
Now i want to sort my View DESC from Value:

```
Hello 155
Foo   140
Bar   100
```

But the only Sorted Version of my View is by Key i get my View sorted by Key ASC.

I tried serval solution on NodeJS side but i dont want to lose much perfomance.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this. Views, by nature, are sorted by key only.  The solution is to create a second view that sorts by a different key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... the problem is that in my db my values are always 1. After the group function the values are counted

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. You can make your values be whatever you want in your map function. `emit(doc.value)` or whatever.  (BTW, there's probably never a reason to emit a value of `1` for all documents. If your goal is counting, there are built-in functions to do that for you)

Answer (score -1):

I build a work around on NodeJS Side:

```
body.rows.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(b.value,10) - parseInt(a.value,10);
});
```

Im not 100 percent satisfied, but the solution helped me. I still cannot estimate how much perfomanace the sorting takes on the NodeJS side